# Given two Hilbert Spaces, one is Isomorphic to a subspace of the other.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces

I suppose I'm doing something wrong as this solutions seems too simple.

We know that each of $\mathcal{H}_1$, $\mathcal{H}_2$, has a maximal orthonormal basis. Suppose $\{u_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ and $\{u_\beta\}_{\beta \in B}$ be these bases and suppose wlog that $|A|<|B|$. Take a subset $B' \subset B$ that is of the same cardinality as $A$. Let $$\overline{P} := \overline{\operatorname{span}\{u_\beta\}_{\beta \in B'}}$$ so that we have an isomorphism $\overline{P} \cong \ell^2(B')$ since $\overline{P}$ is a closed subset of a Hilbert Space and thus a Hilbert Space with maximal orthonormal basis as the restriction to $B'$. Since $|B'| = |A|$, we have an isomorphism $\ell^2(B') \cong \mathcal{H}_2$ and thus an imbedding $\mathcal{H}_1 \hookrightarrow \mathcal{H}_2$ carrying $\mathcal{H}_1$ onto $\overline{P}$ isomorphically.

If this is not correct or incomplete, I would appreciate hints before answers, as this is indeed homework.

Comment: Your proof is fine except that $|A|<|B|$ should probably be $|A|\leq|B|$. The case $|A|=|B|$ is trivial, but it's covered by your argument, so you might as well include it rather than burying it in "wlog".

Comment: @AndreasBlass You're right. Might as well include it.